# Qt application windows moved between multiple monitors make child dialog showing with bug of empty blank windows only

Tags: qt, qwidget, qdialog

[Update on 19 aug 2019 about workaround of this bug]

environements:

System: Windows 7 (reproduced on windows 10 PC on execution too)

QT version: 5.11.2 as well as 5.13

compilation kit: Qt 5.11.3 MinGw 32bits ( mingw53_32 )

I encounter an issue with QDialog in Qt app. it's easy to reproduce, with multiple monitors(eg. 2 screens), you launch your application, then you move your main windows from one monitor to another one, then you click on the button of app to show a child dialog, then it this issue happens. (In my real case not all my qdialog windows get this bug, only some of them. I can't figure out root cause yet.)

Does anyone have an idea how to workaround it?

A simple example is shown in screenshot below:

Main Code of the example:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "Dialog1.h"
#include "Dialog2.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mDialog1 = new Dialog1(this);
    mDialog2 = new Dialog2(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    mDialog1->show();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    mDialog2->show();
}
```

Now I open a small app windows which just contain buttons to open dialogs: 
[image]

-> If i click on button 1 directly, a green dialog opens without problem.

Now I move this windows to my 2nd monitor, and I click on the button, you see the UI of the dialog not showing, just empty windows:

[image]

Now if I move this empty dialog to the other monitor again, I see finally its correct UI showing:
[image]

===============================

After some tests, I found that, when the UI bug happen on the dialogue, doing resize on it helps to make the UI appear.

So I tried below workaround as long as QT framework still present this issue.
Below is the workaround code.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    mDialog1->show();
// ****below is th working workaround, which force resize, so will trigger the paint() or sth on the UI so UI to refresh the correct display.
    mDialog1->resize(mDialog1->width() + 1, mDialog1->height());  // here need to resize to width() + N, N >=1 to make it work.
    mDialog1->resize(mDialog1->width() - 1, mDialog1->height());
...
```

Comment: provide a [MRE], On the other hand it seems like a bug, so it is advisable to report it.

Comment: Tell me what is minimal reproducible example,????? code or what?

Comment: If you want to know what an MRE is then read the link. It also adds the characteristics of the OS and version of Qt. If you do not provide an MRE, your question is probably closed again.

Comment: We have basic rules that help us reduce our working time and thus be able to help other people, if you want help you should strive just as we do when trying to help you.

Comment: modif added, please check

Comment: as a side note: if you provide a MRE,1)  me and others will be willing to test it. and 2) if it seems to be a bug, you can provide that MRE to the developers. Either way you will get more results in your search for an answer/solution.

Comment: @vivi With the information that you have provided to me it seems to me that it is a Qt bug, so to continue discarding problems, have you tried other computers ?, but my best recommendation is that you report it as a bug to Qt since we cannot help you here since it is not a problem of your implementation but it is something internal of Qt.

Comment: if you file a bug, you can mention it works on Windows 10 using Qt 5.13.0 MSVC 2017. just tested it.

Comment: @Eddy Alleman I test the same code, on Windows 7 and QT 5.13, still reproduced.

Comment: I don't understand why i should directly signal to QT developper and can't post here. here we know there is limitation or bug in qt itself, but as I mentioned, it doesn't happen in every QDialog showing, some still work perfectly when switching monitor(systematically working), the idea is to find out how to workaround to make it work with current QT framework, because appearently it's feasible

Answer (score 2):

If it works on my Windows 10 with Qt 5.13.0 MSVC 2017 and it does not on your Windows 7 with Qt5.13, then there must be some differences...What compiler are you using?

How can we determine the differences? 
First of all we cannot test the same program as you have. That's why we asked for a MRE. If you make a MRE, you isolate the problem and sometimes you see the cause by yourself. We can test your program and maybe see some faults there. If you don't provide us with more information, it is simply impossible to help you.

You're right that first we have to determine if this is reproducible before making a bug report.

Comment: that original one I tested on Qt5.11 was with kit "Desktio Qt5.11.3 MinGW 32bit". (so it used the path in mingw53_32)

Comment: Now I test the same code on windows7, with qt creator kit: Qt 5.13.0 MinGW 32-bit (path of 5.13.0\mingw73_32), issue reproduce still.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it the other way around. Can you use my test program on your system? (it is complete with pro file, ui files, h and cpp files, so you will not need to do a lot of work to test it...) It can be used to file a bug report if needed = double reward.

PS: you're supposed to provide an example like that to attract people to test with minimal effort.

Here is the example I tested:
[testDoubleMonitor](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hyg0rk73fas6cbb/testDoubleMonitor.zip?dl=0)

Comment: thanks for help. I tested here on my PC with ur whole project code. windows7, with qt creator kit: Qt 5.13.0 MinGW 32-bit (path of 5.13.0\mingw73_32), issue reproduce still

Comment: then you should make a bug report. do you know how to do it?

Comment: Did you make a bug report. so the community can benefit from your experience?

Comment: I will report it when I have time. Thanks.
Btw, I have found a workaround to make the dialog display properly with some code

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue wherein I would see “blanked out dialog boxes” in my application on multi monitor PC’s 
Specifically if they would be displayed using the blocking exec() call. 
Changing this to use the non-blocking show() and handling the response in slots for accepted () and rejected() fixed it.
Version of Qt used 5.12.4 LTS

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a [QT-BUG](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-76509), have to be aware of is please ignore the discription:

> Bug in Windows 10 is first introduced in 5.12.4, Previous versions
> (<5.12.4) work as intended.

I tested with ***Qt5.12.3+Win10*** also have this problem described in my [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65523405/when-moved-a-qdialog-to-another-monitor-and-close-it-the-dialog-will-be-blank-a), and after updated to ***Qt5.12.10***, *QDialog* worked well.