# When moved a QDialog to another monitor and close it, the dialog will be blank after reopened

Tags: qt, multiple-monitors, qdialog

Env: Win10+Qt5.12.3(msvc)

code:

pro:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += \
        dialog.cpp \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        dialog.h \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        dialog.ui \
        mainwindow.ui
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDialog>
#include "dialog.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void slot_btn_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Dialog *dialog;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "dialog.h"

#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    dialog = new Dialog(this);

    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slot_btn_clicked()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::slot_btn_clicked()
{
    dialog->exec();
}
```

dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QCloseEvent>
#include <QShowEvent>

namespace Ui {
    class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
   void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e);

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Dialog();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

#include <QDebug>

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>

#include <QPushButton>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
    label->setText("this is a label");
    layout->addWidget(label);

    QPushButton *btnaccept= new QPushButton(this);
    btnaccept->setText("accept");
    connect(btnaccept, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=](){accept();});
    layout->addWidget(btnaccept);

    QPushButton *btnclose= new QPushButton(this);
    btnclose->setText("close");
    connect(btnclose, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=](){close();});
    layout->addWidget(btnclose);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *e)
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;

    QDialog::closeEvent(e);

    //e->ignore();  // if ignored close event, working well.
    //accept();
}
```

[demo code pack](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9pf7o86bcl5fx4/QDialogMultiMonitor-src.zip?dl=0)

[Video presentation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbld9lmaadv3kee/QDialogMultiMonitor.mp4?dl=0)

I found that a method of closing *QDialog* will cause this situation: **close button in title bar(top-right corner of the dialog)**, if closing it by *reject()*, *accept()*, *close()* everything is working correctly.

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392069/qt-application-windows-moved-between-multiple-monitors-make-child-dialog-showing) which is similar with mine, but I think the answer (resize the dialog manually) is not perfect, is there any another solution?

Comment: please show your code as text in your post, not external links

Comment: Known problem of 5.12.3 - update to a more recent version: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-76509

Comment: thanks @chehrlic, I have searched this bug early, but its description mentioned “Bug in Windows 10 is first introduced in 5.12.4, Previous versions (<5.12.4) work as intended.” made me think that my situlation (using 5.12.3) does not match this bug. After reminder, I tried the latest 5.12.10 and the dialog worked normally.